# jQuery Tag-It - using a label and value object list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, tag-it

I try an awesome plugin (http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/).

I have an object list like this:

```
var category = [{label:'Photographer',value:'Guruh'},{label:'Photographer',value:'Citta'},{label:'Photographer',value:'Zaki'},{label:'Version',value:'737'},{label:'Version',value:'738'}];
```

Which I pass to the tagSource option in my setup:

```
$("#my_list_tags").tagit({
    tagSource: category,
    singleField: true,
    singleFieldNode: $("#my_list"),
    placeholderText: "Start typing..."
});
```

my current display list : 
[image: current list]

I want to show my display list like this with some extra label :
[image: display list]

Here is my render html :

```
    <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 50px; left: 12px; display: none; width: 294px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
     <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Guruh SKOM</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
     <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">guruh</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Could anyone please help me here? I would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance, Guruh

Comment: can you post the rendered `html` here

Comment: @DON : ok, I already add render html to the question

Answer (score 0):

you can call something like this after your options are rendered

```
var category = [{label:'Photographer',value:'Guruh'},{label:'Photographer',value:'Citta'},{label:'Photographer',value:'Zaki'},{label:'Version',value:'737'},{label:'Version',value:'738'}]; 

$("a.ui-corner-all").each(function(){

     var txt = $(this).text();
     var lblIndex;
     var lblValue;


     $.each(category, function (index, singleObj) {
            if(singleObj.value == txt)
             {
                 lblValue = singleObj.label;
                 return false;
             }
     });         


     $(this).text(txt + " " + lblValue);

});
```

This may be not more complex

Comment: Thank you, But, it is not like that. I have an object (JSON) which are not always (photographer) maybe 'Version' or other.  You can see at the top my question.